# How to retrieve a List from WebService SOAP in Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, soap, xamarin.android

this is my WebService which is connected with a DataBase and i want to list all that in my Android Project using Xamarin:
WebService :

```
public string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DjConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    [WebMethod]
    public List<Clientes> Clientes(/*string _curso, string _turno, string _semestre*/ Sel _sel)
    {
        string Select = "select Nome,Menssagem from Faculdade where Curso = " + _sel.Curso + " AND Turno = " + _sel.Turno + " AND Semestre =" + _sel.Semestre;

        List<Clientes> clientes = new List<Clientes>();

        using (SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Select, conexao))
            {
                conexao.Open();
                SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (dataReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        Clientes cliente = new Clientes();
                        cliente.Nome = dataReader["Nome"].ToString();
                        cliente.Menssagem = dataReader["Menssagem"].ToString();
                        clientes.Add(cliente);
                    }
                }
                conexao.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return clientes;
    }
```

Which Sel class has three props :

```
    public String Curso { get; set; }
    public String Turno { get; set; }
    public String Semestre { get; set; }
```

I create this class to use some conditions to make a query in my database, in Windows Phone Works like that :

```
public MainPage()....{

        Service.Sel sel = new Service.Sel();
        sel.Curso = "'CCO'";
        sel.Turno = "'Manha'";
        sel.Semestre = "'2015'";
        Service.WebServiceSoapClient cliente = new Service.WebServiceSoapClient();
        cliente.ClientesAsync(sel);
        cliente.ClientesCompleted += Cliente_ClientesCompleted;
}
private void Cliente_ClientesCompleted(object sender, Service.ClientesCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lbLista.ItemsSource = e.Result;
    }
```

And Works fine,but in android, i know i will need to use a Adapter to create a list

```
ListBaseAdapter:
```

I want to do the same way there i did in Windows Phone, first past the conditions to make a query and then list all!

Comment: Then just create that adapter and fill the list with this data.

Comment: @ArturMalendowicz do you have some tutorial ? Because maybe its a difference with webservice,or not ?